How to correctly format tkinter widgets so that they expand and work properly?
I cannot seem to get my tkinter program to work properly. I have tried many different solutions, but still cannot get it to work.
Here's my code:
root = Tk()
root.title('GUI')

text = r"""
 _____ _       _     _
|  ___(_)_ __ (_)___| |__   ___ _ __
| |_  | | '_ \| / __| '_ \ / _ \ '__|
|  _| | | | | | \__ \ | | |  __/ |
|_|   |_|_| |_|_|___/_| |_|\___|_|
=====================================
Press 'Y' to start!
Remember to press it at the start of the sum!
You will need to do the first question before starting it
(Start the bot on the second question)
  """

header=Label(root,text=text, font=("TkFixedFont"),justify='left')
header.grid(column=0,row=0)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.grid(column=5,row=0,sticky='ns')
mylist = Listbox(root, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

l1 = Label(root, text='Delay: ')
l1.grid(column=0,row=3,sticky='w')

delayEntry = Entry(root,width=4)
delayEntry.grid(column=1,row=3,sticky='w')

b1 = Button(root, text='Set', command=mainthread.setDelay)
b1.grid(column=2,row=3,sticky='w')
    
mylist.grid(column=3,row=0,sticky='nsew')
scrollbar.config(command=mylist.yview)

root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

mainloop()

What it gave me:
A rubbish looking gui with incorrectly sizing and expanding widgets
bad
What i want:
A good looking gui with correct sizing and expansion of widgets.
good

Study how columnspan and rowspan options in .grid() work. Also put related widgets in a frame.

Make the following changes to your code.
header.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=3)
scrollbar.grid(column=5,row=0, rowspan=4, sticky='ns')
delayEntry.grid(column=1,row=3,sticky='ew')
mylist.grid(column=3,row=0,sticky='nsew', rowspan=4)

Add this too mylist.grid(column=3,row=0,sticky='nsew', rowspan=4)

How about the scrollbar?

Apart from fixing the issue by using correct rowspan and columnspan options, I would suggest to group related widgets into frames because it is more easier to layout the widgets.
Below is a modified code as an example:
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('GUI')

text = r"""
 _____ _       _     _
|  ___(_)_ __ (_)___| |__   ___ _ __
| |_  | | '_ \| / __| '_ \ / _ \ '__|
|  _| | | | | | \__ \ | | |  __/ |
|_|   |_|_| |_|_|___/_| |_|\___|_|
=====================================
Press 'Y' to start!
Remember to press it at the start of the sum!
You will need to do the first question before starting it
(Start the bot on the second question)
"""

header = Label(root,text=text, font=("TkFixedFont"), justify='left')
input_frame = Frame(root) # frame for entry and button
view_frame = Frame(root) # frame for listbox and scrollbar

header.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
input_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
view_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2, sticky='ns')

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# widgets inside view_frame
scrollbar = Scrollbar(view_frame)
mylist = Listbox(view_frame, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
mylist.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=1)

# widgets inside input_frame
l1 = Label(input_frame, text='Delay: ')
delayEntry = Entry(input_frame, width=4)
b1 = Button(input_frame, text='Set')

l1.pack(side='left')
delayEntry.pack(side='left')
b1.pack(side='right')

mainloop()

Result:


May I asked. Why not use grid() instead of pack()?

@toyotaSupra You can use whatever you want as long as it works.
